# Cannot allow duplicate enty in textboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have  a text boxes in every row with same name like this

```
 <tr>
    <g:textField name ="point" value = "" class = "destination_points"  id ="point_0" />
   <input type ="hidden" value ="" name ="pointDistanceMapping.point.id" id ="point_id_0" class="point_id"/>   
 </tr> 
 <tr>
    <g:textField name ="point" value = "" class = "destination_points"  id ="point_1" />
    <input type ="hidden" value ="" name ="pointDistanceMapping.point.id" id ="point_id_1" class="point_id"/>
 </tr>
  <tr>
```

i have to validate that these text boxes should not have same value so how can i do it using jquery...

Comment: ya i have tried with .each function but dint work well

Comment: You might want to post your code so it can be improved/fixed.

Comment: Why can't you use the IDs? They're different.

Comment: i have more number of rows(more then hundreds) so this method is not good one for me... i need some method which loops through all text box which has name "point" or class "destination_points "(becoz they r same) and find if there is duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add all the values in an array one at a time and check to see if it exist before adding. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5CFq/)

```
$('#checkDup').click(function() {

    var textValues = new Array();
    $("input.destination_points").each(function() {

        doesExisit = ($.inArray($(this).val(), textValues) == -1) ? false : true;
        console.log(textValues)
        if (!doesExisit) {
            textValues.push($(this).val())
        } else {
            alert('dup');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nCZmz/4/

Comment: i have more number of rows(more then hundreds) so this method is not good one for me... i need some method which loops through all text box which has name "point" or class "destination_points "(becoz they r same) and find if there is duplicate